# Visual studio 2015 enterprise & 2013 ultimate 'run without debugging' is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

When making any project and making the code without errors, when I press run without debugging (CTRL + F5), for a console application, all it does is run a CMD and display nothing. With a forms app it makes visual studio 2015 (same with 2013)not respond and runs the program in the background. You don't see it but it's in the task manager. Also in 2015 you cannot kill the process. Taskkill does not work and neither does process explorer or process hacker. I have to restart my computer for it to close.

It doesn't work if I run it through the .exe file in the bin/debug folder. Running with admin permissions does not work either. I want to not have to open visual studio up so that i can use my programs. I have tried the repair function in the installer. I have un- and re-installed the program but that didn't work. I would appreciate help. (Note:I am using Visual C# as my language.I have not tested this on VB or F#)
EDIT:Tested this on Ultimate 2013 as well.Same results.I guess it's about my computer then.
EDIT:Tested on laptop and it worked.Problem with my PC

Comment: Is your program doing any kind of looping code?  For example do/while loops?

Comment: @BlackFrog Even the apps without any loops do the same thing.

Comment: Ok. Because you don't have any code to show, why don't you create a "Hello World" console app and run it in release mode. Tell us what happens then.

Comment: @BlackFrog http://prntscr.com/915y35 I put it in release mode trough debug > properties > debug > release from the top left.Running with debugging works.Without doesnt.The windows is not frozen.The little dot thing still flashes on the console window

Comment: Ok. This will take some research. But in the meantime I will update the photo with the screen shot you provided.